# Delete message after a user reacts

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a function in my bot that when I say `$addlist` it sends a message to a to-do channel in my discord server. I have acheived the sending and reacting to the message, but I don't know how to delete the todo when I react to it.
Here is the code:

````
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  var Discord = require("discord.js");
    let msg = message.content.slice(9);
  if (message.author.id !== "502823349110571008") return;
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("New To-Do incoming.")
    .setDescription("```" + msg + "```")
    .setFooter("Sent")
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor("YELLOW");
   client.channels.cache.get(`817477111509024819`).send(embed).then(m => {
       m.react("❌")
   })
}
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Listen for all added reactions and filter:

```js
 client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {

  if (user === client.user) return;

  if (reaction.message.channel.id === "817477111509024819") {

   if (reaction.emoji.name === "❌") {

    reaction.message.delete();

   }

  }

 });
```

**Old (not working in this case):**

After you reacted to the message you can do the following:

```js
// ...
client.channels.cache.get(`817477111509024819`).send(embed).then(m => {

 m.react("❌").then(() => { // React to message

  m.awaitReactions((r, u) => r.emoji.name === "❌").then(() => { // Await reaction with emoji name "❌"

   m.delete(); // Delete the message

  ));

 });

});
```

Comment: There are no erors in console but when I react to one of the messages it does not work.

Comment: That's because the _awaitReactions_ method gets called _after_ the message gets send. So if you have messages which were send already (before you implemented the code snippet) it won't work.

Comment: I know, I used the command to add a todo, then reacted but it did not delete the messagem still no errors in console.

Comment: if (reaction.channel.id === "817477111509024819") {
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Well it works now, but the problem is that when it sends the message, it deletes it right away lmfao

Comment: Oh hell yeah, this worked!! Thank you so much!